# Как передается публичный ключ от Сертификата?

Tags: key, x509certificate

Помогите разобраться, как выглядит процесс передачи по сети, в процессе TLS/SSL соединения публичного ключа нашего и промежуточных сертивикатов?

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно? Вопрос выглядит каким-то общим и неконкретным. Возможно вы опишете, как вы сами представляете себе схему соединения - и акцентируете, что именно вам непонятно? В текущем виде можно написать пару общих слов и дать ссылку -- и это так себе вопрос и так себе ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В TLS есть тип сообщения `Certificate`, которое посылает сервер. Это сообщение содержит только список сертификатов. Первый сертификат в списке, это тот, который будет использоваться для подписи. Следующий за ним - это сертификат, который удостоверяет подлинность первого. И т.д. Корневой сертификат, который должен быть установлен в системе клиента, может быть упущен.

Детальнее можно прочитать в RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2

Сертификаты передаются в X509.v3 формате. Внутри этой структуры находится публичный ключ. Примерный формат данных можно посмотреть в википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_X.509

Более детально в RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1